# Why a least element is a distinct property?

Tags: set-theory

A **Well-Ordered Set** always have a least element iff it's non-empty.

Then why is this a distinct property that has a lot of attention while *having a greatest element property* (like $\mathbb{Z}^-$) has no attention.

Comment: Having a least element is not a particularly interesting property. The fact that *any non-empty subset has a least element* is noteworthy.

Comment: There's nothing preventing you from flipping everything upside down and defining a reverse notion of well ordering in terms of all nonempty subsets having a greatest element, other than common sense and convention: the set of natural numbers is, almost by definition, a more natural exemplar of well ordering than the set of negative integers. (If you do want to define a reverse notion, perhaps it should be call "ill" ordering.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In principle we could repeat the entire theory of well-orders with the words and relation signs flipped such that we speak about "greatest" elements of arbitrary nonempty subsets instead of "least".

Since formal logic doesn't care about the words we use, we would have exactly the same theorems in the new formulations, just in the different direction. But there are some **pragmatic** arguments for spending more attention on the usual concept of well-orders:

- Well-orders have an intuitively appealing **main example** in the form of the natural numbers. There's nothing really comparable for co-well-orders.
- It would turn the intuition about **induction** awry. One main use for well-orders is to construct things by *long induction* over the well order. Here you *imagine* constructing your thing starting with the *first* elements of the order and then your induction hypothesis tells you that there's no way you won't get a unique result for everything. Whereas the underlying *formalism* doesn't care about our ideas of the construction being "spread out in time" (what the induction theorem says is that the whole thing we're defining *just is there*, period), it would certainly make it harder to *think about* if we had to imagine **starting with the last elements** for an inductive construction.

---

Note, by the way that if you *combine* the concepts and want to speak about ordered subsets where every nonempty subset has *both* a least and a greatest element, then you get a rather uninteresting theory out of it: Those orders are exactly the *finite total orders*. So it is essential with some asymmetry in the assumptions in order to get the rich theory of ordinals, even though it is formally irrelevant whether the asymmetry is to one side or the other.

Comment: +1. To sketch (for the OP) a proof of the claim in the last paragraph, supposing $A$ is an infinite linear order we define $R_A=\{a\in A: \exists$ infinitely many $b\in A$ with $b<_Aa\}$, and can now argue that either $R_A$ has no least element, or - taking $\alpha$ to be the least element of $A$ - the set $\{b\in A: b<_A\alpha\}$ has no greatest element, since otherwise that element would be $\alpha$'s immediate predecessor and the immediate predecessor of any element of $R_A$ (if such a thing exists) is also in $R_A$.

Comment: There is a famous German quote, usually attributed to Hilbert, that stresses the point that logic is blind to any naming convention: "Man muss jederzeit an Stelle von Punkt, Gerade, Ebene auch Tisch, Bank, Bierseidel sagen können"

Comment: @StefanMesken: Ein Tisch ist ein Tisch.